# Average data points in a range while condition is met in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a very large dataset with over 400,000 rows and growing. I understand that you are not supposed to use iterows to modify a pandas data frame. However I'm a little lost on what I should do in this case, since I'm not sure I could use .loc() or some rolling filter to modify a data frame in the way I need to.  I'm trying to figure out if I can take a data frame and average the range while the condition is met. For example:

| Condition | Temp. | Pressure |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8 | 20 |
| 1 | 7 | 23 |
| 1 | 8 | 22 |
| 1 | 9 | 21 |
| 0 | 4 | 33 |
| 0 | 3 | 35 |
| 1 | 9 | 21 |
| 1 | 11 | 20 |
| 1 | 10 | 22 |

While the condition is == 1 the outputed dataframe would look like this:

| Condition | Avg. Temp. | Avg. Pressure |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8 | 21.5 |
| 1 | 10 | 21 |

Has anyone attempted something similar that can put me on the right path? I was thinking of using something like this:

```
df = pd.csv_read(csv_file)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
   if row['condition'] == 1:
      #start index = first value that equals 1
   else: #end index & calculate rolling average of range
      len = end - start
      new_df = df.rolling(len).mean()
```

I know that my code isn't great, I also know I could brute force it doing something similar as I have shown above, but as I said it has a lot of rows and continues to grow so I need to be efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY:

```
result = df.groupby((df.Condition != df.Condition.shift()).cumsum()).apply(
    lambda x: x.rolling(len(x)).mean().dropna()).reset_index(drop=True)
print(result.loc[result.Condition.eq(1)]) # filter by required condition
```

OUTPUT:

```
   Condition  Temp.  Pressure
0        1.0    8.0      21.5
2        1.0   10.0      21.0
```

Comment: could you explain how the result statement works? I'm fairly new to python. I don't use it often, I looked up the individual parts of the statement and get the general gist of how it works, but would like to have a deeper understanding of how its working?